# How can I get tweets older than a week (using tweepy or other python libraries)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have been trying to figure this out but this is a really frustrating. I'm trying to get tweets with a certain hashtag (a great amount of tweets) using Tweepy. But this doesn't go back more than one week. I need to go back at least two years for a period of a couple of months. Is this even possible, if so how?

Just for the check here is my code

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = '####'
consumer_secret = '####'
access_token = '####'
access_token_secret = '####'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#ps4",count=100,\
                           lang="en",\
                           since_id=2014-06-12).items():
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: Note that `since_id=2014-06-12` is equivalent to `since_id=1996`, because 2014 minus 6 minus 12 equals 1996.

Comment: You can use the Rest APIs to get tweets older than a week
For more details visit the twitter API reference
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting historical data from Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662151/getting-historical-data-from-twitter)

Answer (score 22):

You cannot use the twitter search API to collect tweets from two years ago.  Per the docs:

> Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week. - [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

If you need a way to get old tweets, you can get them from individual users because collecting tweets from them is limited by number rather than time (so in many cases you can go back months or years). A third-party service that collects tweets like [Topsy](http://topsy.com/) may be useful in your case as well (shut down as of July 2016, but other services exist).

Comment: Twitter opens all old tweets at november 2014:  http://www.theverge.com/2014/11/18/7242477/twitter-search-now-lets-you-find-any-tweet-ever-sent

Comment: This is their search *engine*, is that also true for their API?

Comment: @Luigi not as of now. I just tested it today :(

Answer (score 22):

As you have noticed Twitter API has some limitations, I have implemented a code that do this using the same strategy as Twitter running over a browser. Take a look, you can get the oldest tweets: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

Comment: is this working still? when I try with --since and until options it gives me 0 tweets?

Comment: Did not work for me on Vanilla Ubuntu 12.04, So, I had to install pyquery & lxml first. If anyone gets in the same problem, please do apt-get install python-pip; pip install pyquery; apt-get install python-lxml; Then the script will work. ;)

Comment: For anyone still struggling, you need to have these 2 libs installed as well:

sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't retrieve Retweets

Answer (score 8):

Found one code that would help retrieve older tweets.
https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

To get old tweets, run the following command in the directory where the code repository got extracted.

```
python Exporter.py --querysearch 'keyword' --since 2016-01-10 --until 2016-01-15 --maxtweets 1000
```

And it returned a file 'output_got.csv' with 1000 tweets during the above days with your keyword

You need to install a module 'pyquery' for this to work

PS: You can modify 'Exporter.py' python code file to get more tweet attributes as per your requirement.

Comment: I tried to search tweets for one month duration on 2015 with maxtweets 10000. But it can only get around 200. It seems that the older date it is, the fewer data it can get.

Answer (score 5):

2018 update:
Twitter has Premium search APIs that can return results from the beginning of time (2006):

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium#ProductPackages

> Search Tweets: 30-day endpoint → provides Tweets from the previous 30
>   days.
>
> Search Tweets: Full-archive endpoint → provides complete and instant
>   access to Tweets dating all the way back to the first Tweet in March
>   2006.

With an example Python client:
https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python

Answer (score 2):

Knowing this is a very old question but still, some folks might be facing the same issue. 
After some digging, I found out Tweepy's search only returns data for the past 7 days and that some times lead to buy third party service. 
I utilised python library, [GetOldTweets3](https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/) and it worked fine for me. The utility of this library is really easy. The only limitation of this library that we can't search for more than one hashtag in one execution but it works fine to search for multiple accounts at the same time.

Comment: It didn't work for me. An error occured during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found running the examples in the website you linked. Python 3.7, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

use the args "since" and "until" to adjust your timeframe. You are presently using since_id which is meant to correspond to twitter id values (not dates):

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="test",
                           since="2014-01-01",
                           until="2014-02-01",
                           lang="en").items():
```

Comment: yeah i tried that but that is nor possible, if the date are older than a week the output is just nothing. So I have to use a different method than search i guess but i dont find any other which works

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the Twitter API has the date limitation, but not the actual advanced search as implemented on twitter.com. So so the solution is to use Python's wrapper for Selenium or PhantomJS to iterate through the twitter.com endpoint. Here's an implementation using Selenium that someone has posted on Github: https://github.com/bpb27/twitter_scraping/

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe nobody said this but this git repository completely solved my problem. I haven't been able to utilize other solutions such as GOT or Twitter API Premium.

Try this, definitely useful:

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-scrape-tweets-with-snscrape-90124ed006af

https://github.com/MartinBeckUT/TwitterScraper/tree/master/snscrape/cli-with-python

Comment: Please add the essential part of the link to your answer