# Using tweepy to get old tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've put together this short script to search twitter. The majority of the tweets from this search date back from a year ago. It was in connection with a kickstarter campaign. When I run this script though I only get newer tweets that aren't relevant to that term anymore. Could anybody tell me what I need to do to get it the way I want? When I search for the terms on twitter it gives me the right results.

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = 'x'
consumer_secret = 'x'
access_token = 'x'
access_token_secret = 'x'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


results = api.search(q="kickstarter campaign")

for result in results:
    csvWriter.writerow([result.created_at, result.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print result.created_at, result.text
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214189/how-can-i-get-tweets-older-than-a-week-using-tweepy-or-other-python-libraries

Comment: Yeah I found out about that too. Shame but thanks the help!

Comment: Twitter opens all old tweets at november 2014:  http://www.theverge.com/2014/11/18/7242477/twitter-search-now-lets-you-find-any-tweet-ever-sent

Comment: But not in the API, just in the website search.