# Tweepy Not filtering on Since

Tags: tweepy

I have found many examples of the tweepy cursor where a parameter is "since = "YYYY-MM-DD"".  However, in my code below, it is returning tweets much older than the date I specify.  Why?

```
since = "2017-9-20"
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q="nba -filter:retweets",
                       since = since,
                       rpp=100,
                       result_type="recent",
                       include_entities=True,
                       lang="en", 
                       ).items(10)
tweet.text
```

An example of a tweet it returns is:

created_at=datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 19, 18, 12, 50)
 id=376333795

Comment: does adding a leading 0 to your month make any difference - e.g. `since = "2017-09-20"`?

Comment: Also, how are you accessing the `created_at` variable?

Comment: I tried it with the '0' added with no luck.  Also tried like 10-10, but that's not it.  The created_at variable gets returned with 'include_entities' I believe.  To be fair - I could let it run for a while, get piles of tweets, then filter on that created date - but it seems silly to grab piles of unneeded tweets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at a **different `created_at` than the tweet's**. Perhaps the **user's `created_at`**?

Cuz your code seems correct.

Comment: Thanks - I was concerned about that however the documentation seemed to indicate it was the tweet created date.  Further, there are examples online where it uses that field to filter the tweet date.  Unfortunately I'm still unable to filter on tweet date which seems fairly basic.

Comment: I see. I hope you find an answer to that soon.