# Past tweets using tweepy api

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using tweepy API in spyder to get past tweets.
I'm using search method and passing parameters like query item, count, max_id and since_id but getting tweets not more than 1 week. But I want tweets from past one year.
Is there any API for this.

My python version is 3.5
and spyder version is 3.5.6

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the twitter API to collect tweets older than one week as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214189/how-can-i-get-tweets-older-than-a-week-using-tweepy-or-other-python-libraries) on another stack overflow question.  You would need to used Twitters advanced search and scrape the page. Various methods are discussed in the link i posted.