# Retrieving Twitter data using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using that Python code using Tweepy Library to retrieve Twitter data for a specific hashtag, but the question is i need to retrieve a specific period, for example, from 30 june2013 till 30 December 2013. How can I do that?

```
#imports
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

#setting up the keys
consumer_key = '……………….'
consumer_secret = '……………..' 
access_token = '……………….'
access_secret = '……………..'

class TweetListener(StreamListener):
# A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

  def on_data(self, data):
    print (data)
    return True

  def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)



#printing all the tweets to the standard output
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)



stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener())

t = u"#سوريا"
stream.filter(track=[t])
```

Comment: You can't get that data; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733360/3001761

Comment: but i'm running the code for two days consecutively, retrieving the data. all this metadata for just three weeks ?

Comment: @Hana Could you solve this problem ?

Comment: The system still retrieving the data, i don't want to interrupt it.i'm waiting till the sys finish retrieving the data. but if you want to try by urself, someone submitted another answer you can check it out!!

Answer (score 3):

I am still investigating why I couldn't get the same results using `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, geocode=.., q=query, until=date )`  Maybe it's for this [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662151/getting-historical-data-from-twitter/1733360#1733360). But I could retrieve Twitter data using Tweepy between two dates bty going through these steps.

First, I created a generator of dates, between start Date and end Date.

```
def date_range(start,end):
   current = start
   while (end - current).days >= 0:
      yield current
      current = current + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)  #Based on your need, but you could do it per day/minute/hour
```

Then, I created a `Listener` so I can get the tweets that are created in specific day by accessing to `status.created_at`

Your Code should look like:

```
import tweepy 
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
import datetime 


#Use your keys
consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...' 
access_token = '...'
access_secret = '...'


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

def date_range(start,end):
   current = start
   while (end - current).days >= 0:
      yield current
      current = current + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)  

class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        #api = tweepy.API(auth_handler=auth)
        #status.created_at += timedelta(hours=900)

        startDate = datetime.datetime(2013, 06, 30)
        stopDate = datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 30)
        for date in date_range(startDate,stopDate):
            status.created_at = date
            print "tweet " + str(status.created_at) +"\n"
            print status.text + "\n"  
            # You can dump your tweets into Json File, or load it to your database

stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener(), secure=True, )
t = u"#Syria" # You can use different hashtags 
stream.filter(track=[t])
```

Output:

I just printed the dates to check (I don't wanna spam StackOverflow with the political tweets).

```
tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:01

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:02

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:03

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:04

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:05

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:06

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:07

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:08

-------------------

tweet 2013-06-30 00:00:09

-------------------
```

Comment: Thank you Taha, i'll try that code after the system finishing retrieving the data.

Comment: I have tried your code, it works, but i got only the tweets and the tweet time without the user Id!