# Twitter Search API for around 3 month data

Tags: twitter

I am working since last 3 days to find solution about how we can get old data from twitter api around 3 month over limitation of twitter api about 1 week. can some one help me to know best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting historical data from Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662151/getting-historical-data-from-twitter)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get any tweet for the last 3 months apart if you store them in your own database.

The only solution for you would be to pay Twitter GNIP to access historical data.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API only provides the most recent tweets for a given search, up to ~3200.

The so-called "firehose" and some datasets are available mostly for research or developer purposes.

There are some services which sell custom datasets, including Twitter itself (which purchased Gnip). The [overview by Justin Littman at GWU](https://gwu-libraries.github.io/sfm-ui/posts/2017-09-14-twitter-data) is rather comprehensive.